# A tool for creating bibtex entries from MARC tags?

Tags: bibtex, automation, citing

My library provides citation information for books in several formats, but not as bibtex entries. One standard format is the so-called MARC manual tags, which are human incomprehensible, but at least standard.

Is there a tool that can convert these tags to a nice bibtex entry?

here's an example of MARC tags:

```
FMT BK
LDR 01344nam  2200385   45q0
001 000155833
003 MCM
005 20010608085926.0
008 820506s1981    enka          001 0 eng  
010 |a    80042162 //r854
020 |a 0080264808 (pbk.)
035 |a MITb10155833
035 |a (OCoLC)08160923
035 |a GLIS00155833
035 |a (OCoLC)08161698
035 |a (OCoLC)12231338
040 |a DLC |c DLC |d m/c |d MYG
0411    |a eng |h rus
0500    |a QC718 |b .L48 1981
099 |a QC718.L48 1981
1001    |a Lifshit͡s, E. M. |q (Evgeniĭ Mikhaĭlovich)
24510   |a Physical kinetics / |c by E.M. Lifshitz and L.P. Pitaevskiĭ ; translated from the Russian by J.B. Sykes and R.N. Franklin.
250 |a 1st ed.
260 |a Oxford ; |a New York : |b Pergamon Press, |c 1981.
300 |a xi, 452 p. : |b ill. ; |c 25 cm.
4901    |a Pergamon international library of science, technology, engineering, and social studies
4901    |a Course of theoretical physics ; |v v. 10
500 |a Includes index.
650 0   |a Plasma (Ionized gases)
650 0   |a Kinetic theory of gases.
650 0   |a Solid state physics.
7001    |a Pitaevskiĭ, L. P. |q (Lev Petrovich)
8001    |a Landau, L. D. |q (Lev Davidovich), |d 1908-1968. |t Teoreticheskai͡a fizika. |l English ; |v v. 10.
830 0   |a Pergamon international library of science, technology, engineering, and social studies.
CAT |a CONV |b 00 |c 20010620 |l MIT01 |h 1628
CAT |a AIDA |b 00 |c 20030812 |l MIT01 |h 1037
CAT |a lti0904 |b 00 |c 20090523 |l MIT01 |h 1459
049 |a MYGY
910 |a je870930
949 |a MYGY |b 39080004296429
PST0    |0 Z30 |1 000155833000020 |b PHY |c STACK |o BOOK |d 02 |y 00000 |f N |r MIT60-000339160 |n 0 |h QC718.L48 1981 |a MCM |3 Book |4 Physics Dept. Reading Room |5 Stacks |6 Room Use Only |p Avail
PST0    |0 Z30 |1 000155833000010 |b SCI |c STACK |o BOOK |d 01 |y 00000 |f N |r MIT60-000214187 |n 0 |h QC718.L48 1981 |a MCM |3 Book |4 Hayden Library |5 Stacks |6 30 Day Loan
LDR      nx   22     zn 4500
008 0106230u    0   4   uu   1      
004 000155833
8520    |a MCM |b SCI |c STACK |h QC718.L48 1981 |z
LDR      nx   22     zn 4500
008 0106230u    0   4   uu   1      
004 000155833
8520    |a MCM |b PHY |c STACK |h QC718.L48 1981 |z
SFX 1   |s 0-0-0-1-5-5-8-3-3 |l MIT01 |9 00 |z ~~~~~~~~~ |p Avail |a Click button for available online volumes
SYS 000155833
```

from which I would like to create

```
@Book{PhysicalKinetics,
  author =   {E. H. Lipshitz and L. P. Pitaevskii},
  title =    {Physical Kinetics},
  publisher =    {Pergamon Press},
  year =     {1981},
  address =      {NY}
}
```

or something similar....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that somebody has written a Perl script called [marc2bib](https://web.archive.org/web/20110206125816/http://blog.kulp.ch/2006/12/converting-marc-to-bibtex.html).

Comment: This looks good.

Comment: Was anyone actually able to get this thing going? I compiled and installed the linked MARC library, but the perl script fails at line 5: `use Text::Trim qw(trim);` I failed to find the library that I need to install for this....any help?

Comment: @Yossi: It's a CPAN module - tell CPAN to install both modules cited in marc2bib.pl

Comment: the above link is dead

Comment: The script is at https://web.archive.org/web/20080616063548/http://svn.kulp.ch/misc/marc2bib/trunk/marc2bib.pl

Answer (score 0):

This website:

http://www.dlxs.org/docs/12/class/bib/transforming.html

has a link to another (not sure if the same) marc2bib script in the original answer:

http://www.dlxs.org/docs/12/class/bib/marc2bib.pl

Comment: The above (dlxs) mentioned marc2bib.pl is different from the above linked script. It's tagged by coder "jpw". CPAN search "marc2bib" gives "no results" https://metacpan.org/search?q=marc2bib

Comment: Also check out: https://github.com/xymaxim/marc2bib, which looks recent (~2022 ish)