# Biblatex and MARC Records

Tags: biblatex

Is there a `biblatex` style that is based on `MARC` records?  The notion here is that one maps `MARC` records into bibtex entries with `MARC` field names:

```
@BOOK{smith:303,
MARC240uniformtitle = {My Title},
MARC250editionstatement = {2nd ed.},
MARC300physicaldescription = {xvi, 194, [2], viii, [1], 10-238, [1], 10-148 p., 22 cm. 8vo.},
...
}
```

and then uses a `biblatex` style to create handlists and such.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I guess you could have `biber` map the MARC records automatically to `biblatex`, but I can't explain you in detail how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the MARC record to bibtex. If you can run perl, you can take a look at the perl-script [marc2bib](http://www.dlxs.org/docs/12/class/bib/marc2bib.pl). See the answer to [A tool for creating bibtex entries from MARC tags?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/a-tool-for-creating-bibtex-entries-from-marc-tags).

An alternative is to use MarcEdit and convert the records to a suitable, intermediary format. Have a look at the question [Are there tools for importing from CSV to BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48532/are-there-tools-for-importing-from-csv-to-bibtex/48584#48584) and you may have some ideas.

Comment: This seems more recent? (2022 ish updated) https://github.com/xymaxim/marc2bib